# How to add custom css class for all components where the 'required' property is true in wicket?

Tags: wicket

I'm using the jQuery validator plugin in my wicket application (wicket's version is 8.10). It uses CSS classes for identifying the validator that should be applied to the field. To mark the component as required I use the `FormComponent#setRequired` method. Also, I have my own components (inherited from wicket ones) in which I override the `onComponentTag` method like that:

```
 @Override
protected void onComponentTag(ComponentTag tag) {

    if (isRequired()) {
        tag.append("class", CSS.required(), " ");
    }

    super.onComponentTag(tag);
}
```

also I use following construction for native wicket components:

```
if (field.isRequired()) {
      field.add(new AttributeAppender("class", CSS.required()));
}
```

Is there any way to set this behavior for any FormComponent without overriding onCommponentTag or adding an AttributeAppender for each field object? Any global AttributeModifier or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
Application.get().getOnComponentTagListeners()
  .add(new IOnComponentTagListener() {
     @Override
     public void onComponentTag(final Component component, final ComponentTag tag) {
       if (component instanceOf FormComponent) {
         if (((FormComponent) component).isRequired()) {
          tag.append("class", CSS.required(), " ");
         }
      }
     }
  });
```